# The pushforward of the Liouville volume form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

Let M be a symplectic manifold with symplectic 2-form $\Omega$ provided with an action of a compact connected Lie group G with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Suppose that this action is Hamiltonian. Let $\mu :M \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}^*$ be the moment map associated to this action, and denote by $dm_L:= \frac{\Omega^n}{n!}$, $dim M =2n$, the Liouville volume form on M.

My questions are about the pushforward $\mu_*(dm_L)$: it appears a lot in the texts which speak about  symplectic geometry (that I'm not very familiar with!). My first question Is What is its definition, I know What is the pullback of a a differential form but never knew about what is the pushforward of a differential form?

My second question is what is the intuition behind this definition of $\mu_*(dm_L)$, and why it is important in symplectic geometry?

Thank you!

Comment: push-forward of a differential form by a diffeomorphism means the pull-back by the inverse.

Comment: Thank you for this information! However we could'nt apply it to an arbitrary  moment map, because they are not all diffeomorphism .

Comment: A top-dimensional form like $\Omega^n/n!$ can be thought of as a measure and measures can be pushforwarded. As for the interest of the pushforward $\mu_*(dm_L)$, there are situations where you'd like to integrate over $M$ a function of the form $f \circ \mu$ (with $f : \mathfrak{g}^* \to \mathbb{R}$), and this can be done (perhaps more simply) by integrating $f$ over the image of $\mu$ with respect to $\mu_*(dm_L)$. In view of the Duistermaat-Heckman formula, $\mu_*(dm_L)$ has an interesting structure not a priori expected from a pushforward measure, hence the number of texts on the topic!

Comment: @Jordan Payette, thank you for such an interesting comment! But I don't know how measures can be pushforwarded and why the integral of a function of the form $f \circ \mu $ is equal to the integral of $f$ over the image of $\mu$, and finally what is the interesting structure that $\mu_*(dm_L)$ has ? Could you elaborate more please and if possible could you recommend a reference where I can find these things discussed in more details ?

Comment: Wikipedia's article "Pushforward measure" gives the definition of the pushforward. It also describes the "change-of-variables formula" $\int_{M} (f \circ \mu) dm_L = \int_{\mu(M)} f \; \mu_*(dm_L)$. The interesting properties of $\mu_*(dm_L)$ are given by the Duistermaat-Heckman formula (google it) and related results. There are many texts on the subject; Cannas da Silva's *Lectures on Symplectic Geometry* and McDuff-Salamon's *Introduction to Symplectic Topology* have short sections about it.

Comment: Great! Thank you.